Jakarta EE 8 JTA transaction aborded after 2 minutes
I'm developping with Apach Netbeans 16 and Glassfish 6.2.5 and everytime when I have a transaction that take more thant 2 minutes, the transaction is aborded  with this error :
A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB PaiementreservationFacade, method: public java.util.List dao.PaiementreservationFacade.getPaiementreservationPortemonnaieByPersonne(java.lang.Integer,int)|#]
  jakarta.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Client's transaction aborted
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.useClientTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:334)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.preInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:228)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4001)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1767)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:186)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:64)
    at jdk.proxy60/jdk.proxy60.$Proxy1268.getPaiementreservationPortemonnaieByPersonne(Unknown Source)
    at BusinessService.FactureManager.create(FactureManager.java:931)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.glassfish.exousia.AuthorizationService.lambda$invokeBeanMethod$6(AuthorizationService.java:501)
    at org.glassfish.exousia.AuthorizationService.runInScope(AuthorizationService.java:577)
    at org.glassfish.exousia.AuthorizationService.invokeBeanMethod(AuthorizationService.java:501)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:295)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4241)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:603)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:805)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:552)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor199.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:867)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:804)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:552)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:136)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:113)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor200.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:867)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:804)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:348)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4216)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4206)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:188)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:64)
    at jdk.proxy60/jdk.proxy60.$Proxy1444.create(Unknown Source)

I search everywhere how to increase this time, but impossible.
I know that the exception is send by jakarta.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
I also have this persistence.xml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
    <persistence-unit name="myApp" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/MyApp</jta-data-source>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
   <properties>
       <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
       <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
       <property name="hibernate.dialect.storage_engine" value="innodb"/>
       <!--<property name = "hibernate.show_sql" value = "true" />-->
       <!--<property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="CET"/>-->
   </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>

I have try to add this properties in my persistence.xml :
<property name="jakarta.persistence.lock.timeout" value="1"/>
<property name="jakarta.persistence.query.timeout" value="1"/>

but no change... Also tried with javax and still nothing...
What can I do ? anyone has an idea ?
Thank you for your help
EDIT
I also try to make a pause at the begining of my RESTFull request :
try {
       System.out.println("Sleep starts");
       Thread.sleep(125000);
       System.out.println("Sleep ends");
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

And it's stopping during 125 second and at the first time my code try to do something with the database. I receive the same error... I really don't know what I need to change to continus my program.. Any one has an idea ?

Typically it is related to JTA transaction timeout defined on the server (at least in case of WebSphere), so I'd focus on Glassfish settings that define JTA transactions params, not the application itself. Something like this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/821-0185/ablsu/index.html

Thank you. but I already did that and not working

Disclaimer: I haven't work with glassfish ever, but I have tons of experience with Wildfly/Jboss server ... they are not the same of course, but in practical terms, their behavior its similar, so you know what to search for in google ...
In this case, I used as keywords: "Glassfish 6.2.5 transation timeout" ... I found the following links:

Answer that describes how to configure transaction timeouts
Problem describing why the timeout is not being taken

After reading those two links (I suggest that you do too), I think you have to approaches to configure the timeout of your transactions: One is to configure the transaction service they mentioned, or two, (if your using EJBs, of course), is to create a glassfish-ejb-jar.xml that includes the required timeout for your application ...
You can check the strucutre of such file in the following link

Hello, Thank you I haven't see it before you send it to me.. It makes better way for me.. I tried it, but I can't configure the ejb-jar.xml file because I haven't any ejb-name <ejb-name>localite</ejb-name> and I don't find a way to configure it. I see thisis a mandatory parameter
